# I want to Get URLs Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, web-scraping

I want To scrape data from html but couldn't. In return, I get similar result like this `r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]`. I'm using Jquery.

I'm getting all the titles in text form. But when I try to fetch or want to scrape the a `href=URL` , I couldn't. I want to get the URL of the following articles.

It is returning me only the first URL of the article. I can't get how to fetch them all.

```
$("div.listing.listing-blog.listing-blog-1.clearfix.columns-1.columns-1 > article > .item-inner > h2.title").children().attr("href")
```

Comment: Please show what you tried that isn't working so we can help fix it. . `r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]` is part of a jQuery object itself so seems you are not using approprate getter methods (like attr(), text() etc) for the data you want

Comment: Humm!!, although I just cant get to know. How to fetch the URL's from all the articles. I just need such Jquery Code. Would you help me plz!!

Comment: Well you know enough to be able to get the text.  Show us that part then. Also show how you want the expected results. Please note that SO isn't a free code writing service. Objective is to help fix **your code**

Comment: Hmm indeed, I agree with @charlietfl show us the code thats breaking, not the code your attempting to read with the code thats breaking :-)

Comment: $("div.listing.listing-blog.listing-blog-1.clearfix.columns-1.columns-1 > article > .item-inner > h2.title").children().attr("href")

It's returning me the only 1st href of the article

How to get all.

Div contains articles. I'm able to fetch only the first article URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` to loop over all of them and return an array of the url's

```
const urlArray = $("div.listing.listing-blog.listing-blog-1.clearfix.columns-1.columns-1 > article > .item-inner > h2.title a").map(function(){
  return this.href
}).get()
```